# Any working Javascript Auto Completion or Content Assist for Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse to develop some JavaScript codes where I need auto-completion ( Code Content Assist) available. Is there anyway to activate such a thing for JavaScript codes in Eclipse?

Comment: It should be Ctrl+Space when everything's been set up properly, just like for editing any other language that offers Content Assist.

Comment: @nitind What do you mean by "when everything's been set up properly". That's the question how to set it up properly! Your comment is too general

Comment: It sounded like you just didn't know how to invoke/activate it.

Comment: @nitind That's exactly right and that is why I am asking it here. Side note: Auto completion has to work both in *.js files and in html file whithin <script></script> tags.

Comment: @C_graphics I was thinking literally, as in which menu option or keybinding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the *JavaScript Development Tools* installed, you have to be working with a file in a *JavaScript Source Folder*.  To do that, you can create a JavaScript project or enable an existing project from its **Configure** context menu (right-click->**Configure**->**something JavaScript**). Once that's done, if it wasn't opened automatically, bring up the project's **JavaScript Include Path** property page and create or mark an existing folder as a Source Folder.  That should enable it for both JS files and web pages--assuming you have the web page support from the *Web Tools Platform* installed as well.  To get the entire thing installed, you can follow the instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F .

The defaults during conversion should set it up to deal with JavaScript that's aware of browser objects.

Comment: Eclipse support for javascript really sucks, I downloaded Eclipse Neon, installed Pydev and created a new django project. I then added a couple of .js files in the static folder. Try as I might to get autocomplete to work, to no avail. Only in a single file code assist works to variable and functions declared **in that file only** and no where else. This is useles shit. Eclipse maintainers need to get real and recognize how awful the whole Eclipse ecoshpere has become!!

Comment: It simply doesn't work and the guide is ambiguous. Do you add the JS files yourself and then mark them as source files or do you create a user library and add them that way? If adding yourself, do you "Add JavaScript Library" or "Add Library Folder" on the Libraries tab or use one of the multiple similar options on the source tab? I'm able add my JS files a few different ways, none result in JS code completion. 
Some may have gotten this to work, but they're the exception... this is not a straight forward process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `Javascript Development Tools` component of Eclipse installed. You can install this in `Help > Install New Software`.

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse is best suited for Java and related technologies. Although it has a very basic support for Javascript, like you can use ctrl + O to view all the variables and functions. There is no auto complete support for Javascript.

Comment: Untrue. But as with Java projects, you need to have the tools installed and be working with a source file properly set up within the right kind of project.